# Windows Server Failover Clustering - cannot choose desired subnet when creating

Tags: windows-server-2016, failovercluster, windows-cluster, alwayson

I'm setting up a new WSFC cluster, intended for SQL HA, but that's not actually important as yet.

Node A has:

An IP in Subnet 1:  this is where the machine's "primary" IP is, set by the hoster.
An IP in Subnet 2:  this is subnet intended for dedicated for use with this cluster - for cluster management
An IP in Subnet 3:  this is subnet intended for dedicated for use with this cluster - for Sql AlwaysOn listeners

Node B has Subnets 4,5,6, with the same purposes.

Both Nodes each have 2 NICs - but they're teamed so effectively 1 NIC.

My problem is that when I set up the cluster, via the Wizard, is does not allow me to choose subnet 2 + 5 for the management subnets.  It only allows Subnet 1 + 4.

I do not want to use Subnet 1 + 4, since I cannot guarantee that another machine will not be placed in that subnet, creating an IP conflict.

If I try use powershell, I get similar errors about the IP I want - in subnet 2/5, not being valid:

```
PS C:\windows\system32> New-Cluster –Name sql2  –StaticAddress 10.137.120.52 -Verbose -IgnoreNetwork 10.136.98.0/26,10.70.119.192/26 -AdministrativeAccessPoint ActiveDirectoryAndDns
VERBOSE: No nodes specified. Creating a 1 node cluster on db2.
VERBOSE:    at Microsoft.FailoverClusters.PowerShell.RoleCmdletHelper.ConfigureStaticAddresses(IClientAccessPoint cap)
   at Microsoft.FailoverClusters.PowerShell.RoleCmdletHelper.ConfigureClientAccessPoint(IClientAccessPoint cap)
   at Microsoft.FailoverClusters.PowerShell.RoleCmdletHelper.CreateRole(ConfigurationBase config, Cluster clusterObject, FCCmdlet cmdletObject, String serverNameBase)
   at Microsoft.FailoverClusters.PowerShell.NewClusterCommand.WrappedProcessRecord()
   at Microsoft.FailoverClusters.PowerShell.FCCmdlet.ProcessRecord()
New-Cluster : Static address '10.137.120.52' was not found on any cluster network.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-Cluster –Name sql2  –StaticAddress 10.137.120.52 -Verbose -Ignore ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-Cluster], ClusterCmdletException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PSArgument,Microsoft.FailoverClusters.PowerShell.NewClusterCommand
```

If I play along, and choose subnets 1/4, with the intention of changing it later, the cluster gets set up fine, but I am unable later to edit those IP addresses to be what I want. The dropdown simply doesn't show the other subnets, so it won't validate.  ( I've even tried manipulating it via powershell to get around that, no dice).

**Importantly - the cluster DOES show all 6 subnets, in the networks section.**

[image: Node A and B, each with the 3 I'm expecting]

An IP from subnets 2,3 is added to node A.  An IP from subnets 5,6 is added to node B.  They're both pingable on those IPs.

What am I missing about what makes a subnet eligible for use as the management IPs when setting up the cluster?

Many thanks.